# Script load time reducing

Tags: javascript, performance, pagespeed, page-load-time

We using 3 script file on site and must be 3 file and *ignores all cache* i can't tell you why. 
Load time average 1.2s for each. I am looking for reduce to script load time. Any ideas? Using CDN is may help?

***UPDATE:***

I am using Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization v1.1.3 Nuget package bundling approximately 300 files. I have tested if i use this package everytime bundling thoose files. But when i downloaded bundled files and use them the page load time abouts ms. I am thinking to use gruntjs

Answer (score 1):

minify and use cdn. it will reduce page speed..
one more if possible use async tag for script tags like below.

`<script async scr="foo.js"></script>`